# Where clause applied to two linked columns - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

First, my apologies if the title does not represent the question's purport. Any suggested improvement is welcomed. My question is that I am trying to use `WHERE` clause applied to two columns and these columns represent a relationship. That is, each field from the column `A` is linked in a relationship with the peer field in the column `B`. Hence, using `AND` will bring all possible relationships of `A` fields while I need only one record for each field that highlight the relationship with one record from `B`. The columns are `SUPPLIER` and `BUYER`.
When I try the following:

```
SELECT supplier_id, 
       buyer_id 
FROM   relationships 
WHERE  supplier_id IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) 
       AND buyer_id IN ( 11, 12, 13 );
```

This could show the relationship of the supplier 1 with 11, 12 and/or 13. What I want is to show the relationship between 1 and 11, 2 and 12, 3 and 13.

What I have come up with so far is this:

```
SELECT supplier_id, 
       buyer_id 
FROM   relationships 
WHERE  ( supplier_id, buyer_id ) IN ( ( 1, 11 ), ( 2, 12 ), ( 3, 13 ) );
```

Which in fact works perfectly in case the number of relationship is limited. Now the problem is that the number of records is of rank of hundreds. And it's hugely time consuming to copy these ID's one by one in the aforementioned method. Noteworthy, all ID's in Excel file and arranged in two columns `(SUPPLIER_ID, BUYER_ID)`

Is there anyway to import this data to my query (without using PL/SQL)?

Comment: "Is there anyway to import this data to my query (without using PL/SQL)?"
Do you mean import the data you have in excel into a PLSQL query?

Comment: @Arnab, No, I meant I need to get what I aim at using SQL only (I am pretty sure there is a lot of options in PL/SQL to do that)

Comment: In that case, how do you think we can tell the SQL query which SUPPLIER_ID you are mapping to which BUYER_ID.  What I mean is, how do I understand that supplier_id 1 is mapped to buyer_id 11 and not buyer_id 12, without using the Excel sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import your excel file to a `Temp_table` you can do something like this:

```
SELECT supplier_id, 
      buyer_id 
FROM   relationships 
WHERE  (supplier_id , buyer_id ) IN 
(SELECT T1.supplier_id , T1.buyer_id FROM Temp_table T1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will add nothing to the query I mentioned above. The same problem is I need to copy ID's one be one to my query. Imagine that I have 900 ID's.

Comment: do you have another table which contains `supplier_id` and `buyer_id`?

Comment: I have them in excel file

Comment: can you import them to a table? if you import it to a table it will be so simple for you to solve the problem

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid creating temp table in fact. But yes, that is possible. Thanks

Comment: I prefer JOIN rather than IN

Comment: @realspirituals Any specific reason for this preference?

Comment: Yes. On high volume, performance is better in JOIN though IN is much clear